# Hibernate criteria filter by related entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, criteria-api

I have an entity which has a collection of related entities.

```
public class Student{

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "COURSE_STUDENT_ID" , insertable=false,updatable=false)
private Set <Course> courses;
```

I want to filter students by course names and student class id. For now I have worked it out how to filter by class id but I have no idea how to filter by courseId given that Student entity has a set of courses and the tables are related. I have read some articles but no code matches the one I have already.

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = persistenceStore.createCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Object> criteria = criteriaBuilder.createQuery();
Root<Student> root = criteria.from(Student.class);
List<Predicate> params = new ArrayList<Predicate>();

params.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("classId"),classId));

Predicate[] predicates = new Predicate[params.size()];
params.toArray(predicates);
criteria.select(root);
criteria.where(criteriaBuilder.and(predicates));
Query query = persistenceStore.createQuery(criteria);
List<Student> resultList = query.getResultList();
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Thanks for a great first question.

Comment: not sure about criteria way, however, when I had similar needs I used query language, for ideas see here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/JPQL (as the syntax has used basic ideas from the SQL it has been ease to use for me).

Comment: I understand it @PeterButkovic.But the case with me is that the filters are dynamic.so I cant hard-code query.so,if the user wants to filter by class,I add params.add(criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("classId"),classId));

No problem with classId because it is a property of Student entity itself.Problem comes when the user want to filter by courseName which I have to get through the related collection entity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, there is an error in your Entity: the `JoinColumn` annotation applies to the entity on the inverse side of the relationship, `Course` in your case.

So, if `Course` entity has a property `student`, Student has a property like:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "student")
private Set<Course> courses;
```

and in Course entity you have (here it also states that in the db the table course has a field called "student":

```
@JoinColumn(name = "student", referencedColumnName = "id")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Student student;
```

Read [this link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany) for an entry-level explaination on how to map entity relationships.

Regarding the Criteria Query, since you want to retrieve a List of `Student`S, you can define your CriteriaQuery in a more type safe way:

```
CriteriaQuery<Student> criteria = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Student.class);
```

Regarding the question, you have to join the tables in this way:

```
SetJoin<Student, Course> courses = root.join("courses");
```

or, using MetaModel:

```
SetJoin<Student, Course> courses = root.join(Student_.courses);
```

(had the OneToMany property been defined as a `List` or a `Collection`, you'd have had to use the corresponding `ListJoin` and `CollectionJoin` classes).

on the courses you can apply the desired `Predicate` conditions (supposing that Course entity has a string property called `courseName`):

```
Predicate p = criteriaBuilder.equal(courses.get("courseName"), "name-to-look-for");
```

or, using Metamodel:

```
Predicate p = criteriaBuilder.equal(courses.get(Course_.courseName), "name-to-look-for");
```

Finally, in order to concatenate correctly a list of predicates, you can use (at least) two techniques:

```
Predicate p1 = ...;
Predicate p2 = ...;

criteria.where(criteriaBuilder.and(p1, p2));
```

or

```
List<Predicate> conditions = new ArrayList<Predicate> ();
conditions.add(p1);
conditions.add(p2);
criteria.where(conditions.toArray(new Predicate[] {}));
```

See also this excellent [article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-typesafejpa/).

Comment: Student_ is a class generated by [Metamodel generator](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpamodelgen/1.0/reference/en-US/html_single/). Concerning the error you are getting, it shows OfferDetails and OfferDestinationMapping: are these classes of your project? Did you forget something? Edit your question accordingly

Comment: yes, those are details from the project. SetJoin<Student, Course> courses = root.join("courses"); gives me error, Type mismatch: cannot convert from Join<Object,Object> to SetJoin<Student,Course> this is even after I change to 'CriteriaQuery<Student> criteria = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Student.class);' SetJoin<Student, Course> courses = root.join(Student_.courses); I cannot use this, Student with underscore at the end is not identified.should I add any library for this?

Comment: SetJoin<Student, Course> courses = root.join("courses"); is working now... thanks perissf. U will also look into Metamodel Generator too. :)

Comment: I have edited my answer. Please please please read carefully the 3 links I mentioned, before adding further comments.

Answer (score 0):

type mismatch: cannot convert from cascadetype to cascadetype[]

Answer is:

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;

import this line